Animate SVG along path horizontally responsive
I have an horizontally responsive SVG path that stretch without keeping its ratio, and it's working when using preserveAspectRatio="none" on the tag and vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" on the path to keep it intact. But I also need to animate an element along that same path without losing its aspect ratio.
Here is an example and as you can see it's working if you resize horizontally the wrapper but not for the star that loses its aspect-ratio caused by the global preserveAspectRatio="none" attribute. I can't find a workaround for that and have both the path horizontally responsive and keep the star intact and following the path...


.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    resize: horizontal;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    stroke-dasharray: 6 6;
    stroke-linecap:round;
}
.star {
    fill: red;
}
<div class="wrapper">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 400 200" preserveAspectRatio="none">
            <defs>
                <path id="star" d="M0,24.675L2.679,32.921L11.349,32.921L4.335,38.017L7.014,46.262L0,41.166L-7.014,46.262L-4.335,38.017L-11.349,32.921L-2.679,32.921L0,24.675Z"/>
                <path id="path" d="M0,36.608C0,36.608 64.096,15.519 92.956,48.531C121.816,81.542 101.293,129.283 74.824,115.941C48.354,102.599 68.017,24.7 188.557,73.454C309.097,122.207 261.935,170.513 400,175.664" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
            </defs>
            <use href="#path" class="path"/>
            <use href="#star" class="star" x="0" y="-36">
                <animateMotion dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto">
                    <mpath href="#path"/>
                </animateMotion>
            </use>
        </svg>
    </div>




Is using JS an option? My plan would be to calculate the path in JS while factoring in the aspect ratio. In the actual SVG you can then preserve the aspect ratio.

If by JS you pure JS/TS without third party library yes it can be an option. But I'm not sure on what your exact idea is.

Just realized I am deviating from the task even more than just introducing JS.
My current plan would be to:

Have 2 SVGs. A path SVG and a star SVG.
Overlay them in the DOM.
Path SVG has preserveAspecRatio="none"
Star keeps aspect ratio
Star movement is done via CSS motion path
Use JS to calculate the CSS motion path by factoring in container width and height
Probably also need a resize observer to recalculate the path when container size changes.

even if all this works and would be legit, probably the css animation looks clunky when resizing the container

Do you have a code example about the js/css path calculation ? It's where I don't have a clue how to achieve it. No problem with the observer but really the css animation part taking the path of the other svg with JS is a question mark for me...

Unfortunately we can't change the track of a motion path via transform or prevent unproportional scaling for specific elements.
A workaround could be to update the motion path on resize:

we need to parse the motion path data
add a ResizeObserver
scale the motion path geometry via a helper function (scalePathData())

We can't specify a fixed viewBox – otherwise the animated element would be scaled/"squeezed" as well.
Basically we're updating scaleX and scaleY values on resize based on a comparison between the original motion path bounding box and the resized SVG aspect ratio.
Update: Since a motion path in a <defs> section is not rendered we can't retrieve a bounding box. Therefore, we need to retrieve the bbox from the <use> instance or alternatively from a temporarily appended cloned element (which would be removed afterwards).


let svg = document.querySelector('svg');
let motionPath = svg.querySelector('#path')

// parse path for transformations
let d = motionPath.getAttribute('d')
let pathData = motionPath.getPathData({
  normalize: true
});

// original bounding box of motion path from rendered use element
let bbO = usePath.getBBox();


function scaleMotionPath(svg, selector) {
  let bb = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
  let scaleX = bb.width / (bbO.width + bbO.x * 2);
  let scaleY = bb.height / (bbO.height + bbO.y * 2);

  // clone path data to prevent overwriting
  let pathDataNew = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(pathData));
  let pathDataScaled = scalePathData(pathDataNew, scaleX, scaleY);

  // update path data
  path.setPathData(pathDataScaled)

}

let resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  let svg = entries[0].target;
  let aspect = scaleMotionPath(svg)
});

resizeObserver.observe(svg);



/**
 * scale pathData
 */
function scalePathData(pathData, scaleX, scaleY) {
  pathData.forEach((com, i) => {
    let {
      type,
      values
    } = com;
    let typeRel = type.toLowerCase();

    switch (typeRel) {
      case "a":
        com.values = [
          values[0] * scaleX,
          values[1] * scaleY,
          values[2],
          values[3],
          values[4],
          values[5] * scaleX,
          values[6] * scaleY
        ];
        break;

      case "h":
        com.values = [values[0] * scaleX];
        break;

      case "v":
        com.values = [values[0] * scaleY];
        break;

      default:
        if (values.length) {
          for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i += 2) {
            com.values[i] *= scaleX;
            com.values[i + 1] *= scaleY;
          }
        }
    }

  });
  return pathData;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  overflow: visible;
}

.path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-dasharray: 6 6;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}

.star {
  fill: red;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg>
    <defs>
      <path id="star" d="M 0 -12 l 2.7 8.2 l 8.6 0 l -7 5.1 l 2.7 8.3 l -7 -5.1 l -7 5.1 l 2.7 -8.3 l -7 -5.1 l 8.6 0 l 2.7 -8.2 z" />
      <path id="path"  d="M0,36.608C0,36.608 64.096,15.519 92.956,48.531C121.816,81.542 101.293,129.283 74.824,115.941C48.354,102.599 68.017,24.7 188.557,73.454C309.097,122.207 261.935,170.513 400,175.664" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />
    </defs>
    <use id="usePath" href="#path" class="path" />
    <use href="#star" class="star" >
      <animateMotion dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto">
        <mpath href="#path" />
      </animateMotion>
    </use>
  </svg>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/path-data-polyfill@1.0.6/path-data-polyfill.min.js"></script>



The above example is based on the SVGPathData interface draft structure parsed via Jarek Foksa's polyfill.
The path data manipulation requires a normalization:

all commands need to be absolute
we can't really use a (arc) due too their potential x-rotation angles (we could but it would significantly bloat the recalculation for unproportional scaling) => we convert arcs to cubic approximations (perfectly fine!)

The normalizing parameter does the trick for us
See also

ccprog's library pathfit provides more fine grained controls for a similar dynamic path data scaling
"css-tricks.com:Create a Responsive CSS Motion Path? Sure We Can!" (Contains more ideas – albeit I won't recommend the rather inefficient final solution)


Thanks for this answer. I like the idea behind it but by using getPathData it looks like it doesn't on Firefox for example. But changing the SVG Path seems the way to go, I'll try to search in this direction.

@Mushr00m: fixed we can't get the original bounding box from a hidden element (at least we shouldn't). I'm now retrieving the data from the <use> element instead. Otherwise you may temporarily add a cloned path to get the boundaries

Here we go: Added some more info. I highly recommend to check ccprog's library pathfit that provides more options for path fitting

Thanks for the answer, recalculating the path on resize was indeed the way to go ;-)

JSON.stringify(pathData) would only work on a polyfill. You wouldn't be able to use it on a native implementation.

@Robert Longson: Thanks for your feedback. Frankly I'm not very optimistic we'll get native support for getPathData  very soon – any concrete plans for Firefox nightlies?

@herrstrietzel You kind of have to ask yourself how I'd know how a native implemenation would work if I hadn't already written one and found that out: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1934525

@Robert Longson: I must have missed the memo =) Seriously, that's great news! Frankly, I wasn't yet able to test it in Firefox stable or Dev Edition – Can we already test/enable it via about:config?

Download the source code, apply the patch in the bug to it and build your own copy. And welcome to the bleeding edge.
